# Ajax Error with RStudio DT DataTables Package for Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny, dt

The below Shiny app code below:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
        fluidRow(
            column(12, dataTableOutput('table'))
        )
    ),
    server = function(input, output) {
        output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(iris)
    }
)
```

triggers the error:

```
DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7
```

[image: ajax_error]

using the packages:

```
R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.2, RStudio 1.2.5033

Locale: en_US.UTF-8 / en_US.UTF-8 / en_US.UTF-8 / C / en_US.UTF-8 / en_US.UTF-8

Package version:
  assertthat_0.2.1     backports_1.1.5      base64enc_0.1.3      BH_1.72.0.3         
  cli_2.0.1            colorspace_1.4.1     crayon_1.3.4         crosstalk_1.0.0     
  digest_0.6.23        DT_0.11.3            ellipsis_0.3.0       fansi_0.4.1         
  farver_2.0.1         fastmap_1.0.1        ggplot2_3.2.1        glue_1.3.1          
  graphics_3.6.2       grDevices_3.6.2      grid_3.6.2           gtable_0.3.0        
  htmltools_0.4.0.9002 htmlwidgets_1.5.1    httpuv_1.5.2         jsonlite_1.6        
  labeling_0.3         later_1.0.0          lattice_0.20.38      lazyeval_0.2.2      
  lifecycle_0.1.0      magrittr_1.5         MASS_7.3.51.4        Matrix_1.2.18       
  methods_3.6.2        mgcv_1.8.31          mime_0.8             munsell_0.5.0       
  nlme_3.1.142         pillar_1.4.3         pkgconfig_2.0.3      plyr_1.8.5          
  promises_1.1.0       R6_2.4.1             RColorBrewer_1.1.2   Rcpp_1.0.3          
  reshape2_1.4.3       rlang_0.4.2          scales_1.1.0         shiny_1.4.0.9001    
  sourcetools_0.1.7    splines_3.6.2        stats_3.6.2          stringi_1.4.5       
  stringr_1.4.0        tibble_2.1.3         tools_3.6.2          utf8_1.1.4          
  utils_3.6.2          vctrs_0.2.1          viridisLite_0.3.0    withr_2.1.2         
  xtable_1.8.4         yaml_2.2.0           zeallot_0.1.0
```

with Chrome 79.0.3945. This is using the latest development packages for shiny and DT after the CRAN packages did not seem to work.

Is there a workaround to this problem?

Comment: It works fine for me, might be your computer. Is this on a network behind a firewall? (i.e. company network?) Check here for error resolution: https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/7

Comment: I've tried different browsers, networks, and disabling browser plugins.

Answer (score 1):

Use `server=False`

As in:

```
output$tbl <- DT::renderDT(iris, server = FALSE)
```

Source: https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/642

Answer (score 1):

To avoid setting the server argument for each call to renderDT, change the default

```
formals(renderDT)$server <- FALSE
```

See this other [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65971155/change-the-default-arguments-of-a-function-in-r)

Answer (score 0):

Updating to the GitHub master versions of the two suggested packages (htmlwidgets and jsonlite) seems to have worked as suggested on GitHub: https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/758