# change the default arguments of a function in R

Tags: r, function, plot, regression, lattice

I'm following up on **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62946040/7223434)**. I'm wondering if there is a way to set the default for argument `rug` to `FALSE` and argument `multiline` to `TRUE` in the plots generated by `library(effects)` as, for example, shown below in the code?

```
library(effects)
m <- lm(Fertility ~ Examination*Education, data = swiss)
plot(allEffects(m), rug = FALSE, multiline = TRUE)   # By default, change `rug = FALSE`
                                                     # `multiline = TRUE `
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you're just trying to add those two options to @MrFlick's answer you reference, you could do the following:

```r
plot.efflist <- function (x, selection, rows, cols, graphics = TRUE, 
                          lattice, rug = FALSE, multiline = TRUE, ...) 
{
  lattice <- if (missing(lattice)) 
    list()
  else lattice
  if (!missing(selection)) {
    if (is.character(selection)) 
      selection <- gsub(" ", "", selection)
    pp <- plot(x[[selection]], lattice = lattice, rug = rug, multiline=multiline, ...)
    pp$x.scales$tck=c(1,0)
    pp$y.scales$tck=c(1,0)
    return(pp)
  }
  effects <- gsub(":", "*", names(x))
  neffects <- length(x)
  mfrow <- mfrow(neffects)
  if (missing(rows) || missing(cols)) {
    rows <- mfrow[1]
    cols <- mfrow[2]
  }
  for (i in 1:rows) {
    for (j in 1:cols) {
      if ((i - 1) * cols + j > neffects) 
        break
      more <- !((i - 1) * cols + j == neffects)
      lattice[["array"]] <- list(row = i, col = j, 
                                 nrow = rows, ncol = cols, more = more)
      pp <- plot(x[[(i - 1) * cols + j]], lattice = lattice, rug=rug, multiline=multiline,
                 ...)
      # hack to turn off opposite side tick marks
      pp$x.scales$tck=c(1,0)
      pp$y.scales$tck=c(1,0)
      print(pp)
    }
  }
}
environment(plot.efflist) <- asNamespace("effects")

library(effects)
m <- lm(Fertility ~ ., data = swiss)
plot(allEffects(m), rug = FALSE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Note: The below suggestions refer to the general case of changing default values in a function.

Yes, messing with the default arguments is possible. One way is to modify the `formals` of the function, in this case that would be

```
formals(effects:::plot.eff)$rug <- FALSE
formals(effects:::plot.eff)$multiline <- TRUE
```

Another possibility is to use the `default` package like

```
default::default(effects:::plot.eff) <- list(rug = FALSE, 
                               multiline = TRUE)
```

To cite the package description,

> A simple syntax to change the default values for function arguments, whether they are in packages or defined locally.

For more information on the package, you can look up the CRAN page.

Comment: Thanks, but, when I tried your first solution and then did `plot(allEffects(m))`, then I got the following error:
`Error in plot(allEffects(m)) : 
  call to standardGeneric("plot") apparently not from the body of that generic function`

Comment: Did the second solution work? In case the first solution doesn't work you would need to look up how `allEffects()` calls the `plot()` function. Maybe it is necessary to apply the `formals()` to the `allEffects()` or a similar function instead.

Comment: I didn't try the second solution, but I specifically am wondering why the first solution is producing this error, apparently you'r not getting this error, right? On the other hand, did you check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62946040/7223434) to a related question? Maybe we should change the default in the `formals(effects:::plot.eff)` object.

Comment: It's bizarre. The `effects:::plot.eff` objekt **does have** a `rug` property but setting it `FALSE` gives an error in `loadNamespace`. Let me think about how to handle that exception.

Comment: @Taufi I think the `loadNamespace` error is because the function isn't exported from the namespace.  I downloaded the package and exported `plot.efflist` and `plot.eff` and re-installed from this local version.  The error stopped, but using either of the methods above (even if you specify them both on `plot.efflist` and `plot.eff`, which is called by the former, doesn't seem to result in the expected plot - it still has rugs and is not a multi-line plot.